# Code to change Metro-style GUI not working vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm working with MetroFramework and I'm looking through a form of settings to change the color interface with this function:

```
Dim m = New Random()
Dim [next] As Integer = m.[Next](0, 13)
Form1.MetroStyleManager1.Style = DirectCast([next], MetroFramework.MetroColorStyle)
```

It is activated with the push of a button, but apparently the color is not changed. There is no error is shown, but for some reason the window color, and other components remain the default.
How is this possible?

Comment: Works just fine when I try it on the Demo.  Is your form derived from MetroForm?  Why are you not updating Form1.StyleManager.Style?

Comment: What do you mean "derived" from Metroform?
I put this code in my form settings, so I have to call components in Form1 which is precisely the window where I want it changed the graphics.

Answer (score 0):

On VB.NET:

1. If you successfully imported all the metro controls, find the `metrostylemanager` in the list and add it to your form. It will appear as `MetroStyleManager1`, exactly like adding a timer.
2. Select it (`MetroStyleManager1`) and modify its properties to:

   - modifiers: public
   - Owner: `<select your form>`
3. The way I'm changing the colors (no need to import anything):

   ```
   MetroStyleManager1.Style = MetroFramework.MetroColorStyle.Red
   ```